# How to remove grid from line chart of Echart library

Tags: charts, linechart, echarts

I will draw a line chart by echart library. When I draw a chart, it shows grid too. I do not need grid, but I cannot remove it. I have checked out [Echart options](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#grid.show) and I know that grid:{show=false} is an option of echart but it is not effective. My snippet code is below.

```
function lineGraph(xAxisLabels){    
var echartLine = echarts.init(document.getElementById('myElineChart')); 
  echartLine.setOption({
    grid: {show: false},
    xAxis: [{
      type: 'category',
      showGrid: false,
      data: xAxisLabels
    }],
    yAxis: [{
      type: 'value',    
    }],
    series: [{
      name: 'Actual',
      type: 'line',
      data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
    }],
  });}
```

The result is below:
[image]

I appreciate it if you help me.

Answer (score 29):

I'm late to the party, but answering this question if anyone in the future needs help.

It's a good guess to think that this is because of the grid attribute, but the grid is actually set to false by default. The lines are generated by an attribute on your X *and* Y axis, called splitLine, which makes it look like a grid. You can remove it by changing the attribute like shown below:

```
function lineGraph(xAxisLabels){    
var echartLine = echarts.init(document.getElementById('myElineChart')); 
  echartLine.setOption({
    grid: {show: false},
    xAxis: [{
      type: 'category',
      showGrid: false,
      data: xAxisLabels,
      splitLine: {
         show: false
      },
    }],
    yAxis: [{
      type: 'value',   
      splitLine: {
         show: false
      },
    }],
    series: [{
      name: 'Actual',
      type: 'line',
      data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
    }],
  });}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
xAxis: {
    axisLine: {
        show: false, // Hide full Line
    },
    xisTick: {
        show: false, // Hide Ticks,
    },
}
```

Full result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use splitLine property in yAxis or xAxis in options object

```
yAxis: {        
        splitLine: {
            show: false
        }
    },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).